# Catel 4.0.0 and Dependency on Microsoft.Bcl.Build

Tags: c#-4.0, catel

When updating a project to use current Catel version (4.0) I am getting this warning:

> All projects referencing MyInfrastructureProject.csproj must install nuget package Microsoft.Bcl.Build. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317569.

The error is reported for projects that references MyInfrastructureProject.csproj.

I find it odd that I need to add additional libraries to other project especially when it is concerned with nuget (if I am getting the picture correctly) and not with actual functionality of my code (or maybe even Catel). But in any case, I don't really understand the issue.

I searched a little for this issue but didn't find relevant details or explanations.

Should I go ahead and add the Microsoft.Bcl.Build reference everywhere in my project?

Thanks,

Tomer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know what is [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/p/asynctargetingpackkb.aspx) you should study it.

[Catel](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Catel.Core/) uses this feature pack so as to use async/await on .NET 4 and Silverlight 5. So if you use Catel in a .NET 4 project, you inherit the same dependencies, which is what the warning says.

Thus, yes, please go ahead and add the NuGet package to the necessary projects, or simply upgrade your projects to .NET 4.5 and reapply the NuGet packages.